# Как правильно спарсить массив из JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, парсер, ethereum

Нужно вывести на сайт 10 последних транзакций на кошелёк. Значения берутся отсюда: https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=0xF8F118946e56CDe03eD0bc9d29D2b5854130c80f
Нужен вывод таблицей значений from, to и value.

Написал такой код, но в выводе пишет undefined. В чём ошибка? Я новичок ещё в этом. +ещё не понял как брать только последние 10 строк.

```
$(function() {
$.getJSON('https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=txlist&address=0xF8F118946e56CDe03eD0bc9d29D2b5854130c80f', function(data3) {
console.log(data3);
           var out = '';
            out+='<table>';
            out+='<tbody>';
            for (var key in data3){
                out+='<tr>';
                out+='<td>'+data3[key]['from']+'</td>';
                out+='<td>'+data3[key]['to']+'</td>';
                out+='<td>'+data3[key]['value']+'</td>';
                out+='</tr>';
            }
                out+='</tbody>';
                out+='</table>'; 
            $('#result').html(out);
        });
});
```

То что в консоли.

```
Object
message: "OK"
result: Array(25)
0: {blockNumber: "6574814", timeStamp: "1540385519", hash: "0x152e8729dc30275ca49c43473deaecc785bb8463a7510aae7c8b103798722798", nonce: "0", blockHash: "0x32195e62201abd092fdb15c5581b97be179687df551ad2509798beec551cfbd0", …}
1: {blockNumber: "6574834", timeStamp: "1540385772", hash: "0x4e61dbc04f5127f3487ed51fc62eb82cf8bbeb5fc7bd81164b84bc033c4cd3bf", nonce: "1", blockHash: "0xe236cfdbde5be0d6f769fbe33e545a4ea868d768248e8461e275b391f2e4df90", …}
2: {blockNumber: "6574897", timeStamp: "1540386775", hash: "0x0bfb7cdf03fcaca401b7c1b2bff3cbbaf2d85a17b380d664d1c0d4317180ccfd", nonce: "0", blockHash: "0x882934bcbb72421a18f6e18d3dd1fd54591bec8223624751793de09ccc1d93fd", …}
3: {blockNumber: "6574937", timeStamp: "1540387251", hash: "0x0cba83618060a3e9f493e85bcf30a8dd6853ba8e9c329a712d311d48788a363f", nonce: "2", blockHash: "0xd3f18cb9e2c1bf7a3325608fc206687927d99f8be484790fd4fb18b14b818f65", …}
4: {blockNumber: "6575461", timeStamp: "1540394359", hash: "0x663373251077fc9539fce7f82ec8e39826ebcf980ab069759997fbb8dfc49851", nonce: "0", blockHash: "0x6e07ef7b6f0323b54ec15379ddbf7b67a9d22055b93b1802c56bd7b7628b010c", …}
5: {blockNumber: "6575697", timeStamp: "1540397746", hash: "0xed6764bd551d5ff8b2a42750fbe0febf7553e96daac771ff79f2f7b99a0f3317", nonce: "0", blockHash: "0x4f3860d18e4487b34de7467ba985a3110a6ba67cd102bfdfab7e8b148b4affe6", …}
6: {blockNumber: "6575967", timeStamp: "1540401227", hash: "0x643cac1c1c563ff4924af6a822181a21f267c492c169651e39a011b21b453046", nonce: "0", blockHash: "0x2a5727a0194149e16134ce1221113a4230ed62edeaf320174d2b9f3fb0f1074c", …}
7: {blockNumber: "6580991", timeStamp: "1540472421", hash: "0xe6c2f4a6109a43078fab96901c6fea8737ae5a54f5aee47fb4f6b028c2368594", nonce: "1", blockHash: "0xde4d0a674d49ccdc7ec6be23e3ef9265f69b71ea5deed52544848ae8a6718c0f", …}
8: {blockNumber: "6581056", timeStamp: "1540473384", hash: "0x61e2e1ffa009751ab8d6dfdcfabecf67bb8929a0ea71b912d51ce90b0e64f359", nonce: "2", blockHash: "0x19409cbc06fd6d74cbf071a6809cb1d64dae9b83ec55c02031e4fff80ff912ef", …}
9: {blockNumber: "6581824", timeStamp: "1540483779", hash: "0x2b80e44e11c65f95ba28d06894930f4317bc0e7727ca622e3cbf3f0fbfa11bd0", nonce: "1", blockHash: "0x5d90e42358a6fc45ad4f9bb1d3fed1b254b944885ddc2ea49b1bebe905607263", …}
10: {blockNumber: "6582078", timeStamp: "1540487303", hash: "0xfaa6d1545d17a186395cc8140a57c50c744935d446e28cd6dd9146abecde6546", nonce: "2", blockHash: "0x3e1dcf52df191adfba1c726aaa41c9082754b8b20b8c0c7bf5db86ac680eccac", …}
11: {blockNumber: "6582603", timeStamp: "1540494800", hash: "0x9e6ab47849092e2985b131c986acfa2435fbfd70ffbc6d0032ceb5d836a0fd09", nonce: "1", blockHash: "0xbc2b1a6c9f38263edbe18c0992ff6170b0809d64bff931ddbd3daec7b81a9ffd", …}
12: {blockNumber: "6582650", timeStamp: "1540495535", hash: "0x9537799a25629682f49347a194ba0a12d59e2286a268ae55a78553f1b5187466", nonce: "1", blockHash: "0xcd6701fdfeed5bd87fdf3c590e763139aa698604f483befc296c17d71286c8a9", …}
13: {blockNumber: "6587180", timeStamp: "1540560014", hash: "0x515969785755f969f2117f35ea41b8d549c6d7f059be8f3d1f97fb7ca20e91d4", nonce: "3", blockHash: "0x5e8c2f3996972bd0cd3208133f3262cebbaab893c7eb1a56053e74f8571af6f6", …}
14: {blockNumber: "6587791", timeStamp: "1540568247", hash: "0x770f9b33169882ae9284f136155f2eb61fd9651d831102bf908a630f14960721", nonce: "4", blockHash: "0x2874e8d30e83208b6bebbc184b6845ba3037260b7487dca7b79ea0e14e9cdeb4", …}
15: {blockNumber: "6587872", timeStamp: "1540569463", hash: "0xc61e54f5bab447fac80c39493711bf1211c3f57c0fd6024146b8b809b22a3b2c", nonce: "5", blockHash: "0xa1888712a38b2f3752ad69c6d4869946417d2dcf038c645ef88e267c4dfda326", …}
16: {blockNumber: "6587925", timeStamp: "1540570212", hash: "0xf2371e26d96c7dd1dec57228db7a7d0e54034da27e4aef064c92d78575638a06", nonce: "6", blockHash: "0xfd3966863580d1644223adc29a41dae9c9bdfa8e0c0d3b580ce8ba8312a808c2", …}
17: {blockNumber: "6588006", timeStamp: "1540571411", hash: "0xe11131a225ff3dcfd64b3556ce01afb2564ad6238c757dc24ce92fd24149a3cc", nonce: "7", blockHash: "0x3979ff832ab8119c3187ff9f976e78d34fb1fd42b3a60c6fba8222c83d607f06", …}
18: {blockNumber: "6588435", timeStamp: "1540577483", hash: "0x9b7d3df898e1d211bb0d85b38a7b4e5bb39838deb52430763e6fa238a79fb36b", nonce: "0", blockHash: "0xfb270f532d528609e7897b9db10149e8085b144677cc9afd6232be15073b10c2", …}
19: {blockNumber: "6592709", timeStamp: "1540637471", hash: "0x2f18e7579d98daa63d4a965d54c876e664563e825696abb9c07201d642d442be", nonce: "0", blockHash: "0x98c5c6725bfdbaaea85e6521ae82adebf73078742cf2694e5dcaca4826021d28", …}
20: {blockNumber: "6592756", timeStamp: "1540638251", hash: "0xb9b82d28f98e4ac31fc77b6e86d8a48fd5eb1e742cd616030f69f4b177f9f5c2", nonce: "1", blockHash: "0x4a11eb41aafd9b049f736bb2fd8c9acc1cdf5c8e911f4a4b981b70653434bf67", …}
21: {blockNumber: "6592793", timeStamp: "1540638840", hash: "0xc7cce4bef715873b01974dfe276294d008b4b79c72f21a015d3dbe54139af166", nonce: "2", blockHash: "0xbfe4775ee62044eff985677545caf9e5a6645e09ac3191e8a6f7d952bbc75b84", …}
22: {blockNumber: "6592821", timeStamp: "1540639286", hash: "0x4b977f5c0181aa306f866d37881c8f5a44cfefb60cb560e9f305f42adc9af160", nonce: "24", blockHash: "0x3c302e2580c96f45eac8fab03e13c6036c368c102b40ace20fd0608390df080b", …}
23: {blockNumber: "6592835", timeStamp: "1540639457", hash: "0xeee1ce780322db1033e5b773c9ad4090d9b60278cb4f469447c37e6c250ff36c", nonce: "25", blockHash: "0xc4afbf560d73863759e085cd8da6d175a22d8daa53904177ddebc61633915a36", …}
24: {blockNumber: "6592931", timeStamp: "1540640971", hash: "0x3b525d15bca131fbf5de2b9599d294a45498b733d430fd2d75e8ae0739a2e93c", nonce: "26", blockHash: "0xadf2bbb59439d1cb9406dafa7bea8c3e40b3c7a683ee54afe89554d7712df668", …}
length: 25
__proto__: Array(0)
status: "1"
__proto__: Object
```

каждая строка содержит значения (пример):

```
blockHash: "0x98c5c6725bfdbaaea85e6521ae82adebf73078742cf2694e5dcaca4826021d28"
blockNumber: "6592709"
confirmations: "328"
contractAddress: ""
cumulativeGasUsed: "3465998"
from: "0x1074cbe865959f265d383f6d10e114bccd0cc6fe"
gas: "249122"
gasPrice: "9000000000"
gasUsed: "249122"
hash: "0x2f18e7579d98daa63d4a965d54c876e664563e825696abb9c07201d642d442be"
input: "0x99d8935f80280ff4672ec4c969a8b2aee970c092"
isError: "0"
nonce: "0"
timeStamp: "1540637471"
to: "0xf8f118946e56cde03ed0bc9d29d2b5854130c80f"
transactionIndex: "123"
txreceipt_status: "1"
value: "5005000000000000000"
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: `console.log(data3);` - что вывелось в консоль?

Comment: написал выше вывод

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предполагая, что у элементов массива помимо свойств `blockNumber`, `timeStamp` и т.п. все-таки есть свойства `from`, `to` и `value`:

```
        var out = '';
        out += '<table>';
        out += '<tbody>';
        for (var i = 0; i < data3.result.length; i++) {
            out += '<tr>';
            out += '<td>' + data3.result[i].from + '</td>';
            out += '<td>' + data3.result[i].to + '</td>';
            out += '<td>' + data3.result[i].value + '</td>';
            out += '</tr>';
        }
        out += '</tbody>';
        out += '</table>'; 
        $('#result').html(out);
```

> как сделать вывод только последних 10 записей (строк) из массива, у
>   которые значение value > 0?

```
var i, last10 = [];
for (i = data3.result.length - 1; i >= 0 && last10.length < 10; i--) {
  if (data3.result[i].value > 0)
    last10.push(i);
}

var out = '';
out += '<table>';
out += '<tbody>';
for (i = last10.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  out += '<tr>';
  out += '<td>' + data3.result[last10[i]].from + '</td>';
  out += '<td>' + data3.result[last10[i]].to + '</td>';
  out += '<td>' + data3.result[last10[i]].value + '</td>';
  out += '</tr>';
}
out += '</tbody>';
out += '</table>'; 
$('#result').html(out);
```

Comment: Да, сработало, спасибо! Но как сделать вывод только последних 10 записей (строк) из массива, у которые значение value > 0?

`if(data3.result[i].value > 0) { ... }`